# Cyclic group of order 2012 and primitive roots

Tags: group-theory

G is cyclic of order 2012
Is $g^{537}$ is also a generator of G?

If $2012$ has no primitive roots does it says that no?

Comment: Primitive roots are not needed here because you were given the cyclicity of the group as a fact. Have you checked $\gcd$?

Comment: The question is confusing, but that is what I find interesting.  If $G$ is a group of order $2012 = 2^2*503$ then $G$ does not have primitive roots.  If $g \in G$ has order 2012, then the order of $G$ is larger than $2012$.  Since $2013 = 3*11*61$ is not prime nor twice a prime that would not work.

Answer (score 1):

It is a theorem that in $\mathbb Z_n$, if $g$ is a generator then $g^k$ is also a generator if, and only if, $gcd(k,n)=1$. Now, your $G$ is cyclic, so it is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{2012}$. So, to answer the question go ahead and check if $gcd(537, 2012)=1$.